# Splitting Ordered Array of Items to Alternating Columns in HTML

Tags: css, arrays, html

I'm trying to create a responsive HTML layout which will display an array of ordered data.

On a smaller screen size, it will display one column of content in order. However, on a larger screen size, it'd display two columns with the items alternating between the two columns.

**Ex: Small**

```
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
```

**Ex. Large**

```
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
```

Adding onto this, in the two column layout, the elements in the left column should be `float: right`, while the right column should be `float: left` so that they meet up in the center no matter the width of the elements.

The only idea I've come up with so far is to create two column containers, one that will float all elements right and one that floats all elements left. However, I have yet to figure out how to distribute the items in the order array so that I won't have to split it up into two, since that will mean that when changing screen sizes to the smaller one, the one column of items would no longer be in order.

---

**Edit 1:** Each element may not have the same height, and when placing the element, it should go onto the height that has the smaller overall height.

```
|    ------|----------|
|    |  1  |     2    |
|    |     |----------|
|    |     |   3   |  |
|    ------|-------   |
```

This is a sample [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nth5uu70/4/) of approximately what I'm trying to do, except perhaps less-hacky. The layout I'm trying to achieve is similar to [this](http://www.loisjeans.com/web2012/es), except the elements have a specific order.

Comment: Why not use a framework that can solve you this, like bootstrap for example?

Comment: Use a CSS flex-box or inline-block?

Comment: @Dekel Sorry, I don't think I was displaying the edge case for the layout (which I've added in Edit 1), which I don't think any of the Bootstrap layouts would be compatible with it.

Comment: Flexbox! http://flexboxin5.com/

Comment: @user2182349 I would probably use flexboxes over floats, but still need an actual HTML structure to create the edge case in Edit 1.

Comment: @mparnisari Is there a way to create the layout in Edit 1 using flexboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some testing, a friend and I decided that this was probably the best way was to use `display: flex` on left elements while using `float: right` on the right elements as shown in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nth5uu70/8/).